# Returning specific repository by interface

Tags: c#

I have following structure of code as below. I have currently two repository classes which both implements so far one generic interface with single method. They only pass diffrent return type object. I also have Factory pattern class to retreive specific repository. My problem is in my RepositoryFactory i get error message shown below. To be honest i have no idea what should be done. Counting on your support.

**Errors:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T :class 
{
   IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
}

public class CsvRepository : IRepository<InputData>
{

   private string _path;

   public CsvRepository(string path)
   {
       _path = path;
   }

   public IEnumerable<IBasic> GetRecords()
   {
       return from line in File.ReadLines(_path)
              select line.Split(',') into parts
              where parts.Length == 3
              select new InputData { Name = parts[0], X = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), Y = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) };
    }
}

//other repositories:
public class OracleRepository : IRepository<OtherDataType>
{
..
}
...


//Factory pattern to get specific repository on demand
//Implement IoC later on (register instead of cases)
public class RepositoryFactory
{
   public static IRepository GetRepository(DataSource repositoryType)
   {
      IRepository repo;
      switch (repositoryType)
      {       
         //break;
         case DataSource.Csv:
              repo = new CsvRepository("path"); //perhaps path shoudln't br right passed right here - so where?
              break;
         case DataSource.Oracle:
              repo = new OracleRepository();
              break;
         default:
              throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Type");
      }

   return repo;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I was trying to just make simpler - non generic interface on top of my current one like this:

```
  public enum DataSource
    {
        SqlServer,
        Csv,
        Oracle
    }
  public interface IRepo
    {
    }
```

so:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IRepo
```

then i tried:

```
public static IRepo GetRepository(DataSource repositoryType)
        {
            IRepo repo;

            switch (repositoryType)
            {
                //case "Service":
                //    repo = new ServiceRepository();
                //    break;
                case DataSource.Csv:
                    repo = new CsvRepository("path"); //perhaps path shoudln't br right passed right here - so where?
                    break;
                case DataSource.SqlServer:
                    repo = new SqlRepository();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Type");
            }

            return repo;
        }
```

however then i get errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'CsvRepository' to 'IRepo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  
Cannot implicitly convert type 'SqlRepository' to 'IRepo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: `IRepository<T>` is a generic type.  You can't declare it without specifying the generic type.

Comment: @BJMyers ye i know  but this interface is used base for diffrent repositories. Should i create special non T - generic interface and implement in all repositories just to be able to use my repositories in Factory pattern method or is there any more suitable approach? Or maybe some other approach like IRepository --> IRepository<T> : IRepository and use IRepository in Factory method? Not sure.

Comment: @BJMyers Look at my main post in EDIT clause what i was trying so far..

Comment: @and last one: What do you think about passing path into ctor of CsvRepository - currently i have it in GetRepository method, however i do not think it's good approach, where it should be passed then? Also other information pass into other repositories. In current solution object is created in GetRepository method so means in ctorts of it all will be there - please of advice because i do not think getfactory is not right place for that. By the way i would need to also pass those information through GetRepository parameters... not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more abstraction level for your data so that new abstraction will be used in generic :

```
public interface IBasic { }

public class InputData : IBasic { }

public class OtherDataType : IBasic { }
```

Now, your IRepository should written against IBasic interface

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IBasic
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
}
```

Now, you can have concrete implementation for above IRepository:

```
public class CsvRepository : IRepository<IBasic>
    {

        private string _path;

        public CsvRepository()
        {
            var filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFileName"];
            _path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + filename;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IBasic> GetRecords()
        {
            _path = "Read path";
            //Implement Yield & iterator here !!
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    //other repositories:
    public class OracleRepository : IRepository<IBasic>
    {

        private string _path;

        public OracleRepository()
        {
            var filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFileName"];
            _path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + filename;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IBasic> GetRecords()
        {
            _path = "Read path";
            //Implement Yield & iterator here !!
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Now, your factory looks like this :

```
 public class RepositoryFactory
    {
        public static IRepository<IBasic> GetRepository(DataSource repositoryType)
        {
            IRepository<IBasic> repo = null;
            switch (repositoryType)
            {

                //break;
                case DataSource.Csv:
                    repo = new CsvRepository();
                    break;
                case DataSource.Oracle:
                    repo = new OracleRepository();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Type");
            }

            return repo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks very nice, let me check firstly (will not forgot about mark as answer). By the way, can you tell me additionaly, why my try from EDIT seciton of my main post giving mentioned error?

Comment: would appreciate your additional answer. Thanks !

Comment: @JimmyJimm : I don't see any issue with your abstraction. Can you please post your whole code which is implemented by various concrete repository.

Comment: I added more code i think its enough to say why i get this bottom error which appears at following lines:  repo = new CsvRepository(); repo = new SqlRepository();  (note that i am talking about my EDIT main post section code.

Comment: If in OracleRepository in function public IEnumerable<IBasic> GetRecords() i would like to implement Yield ... how to make it as long as function doesn;t know what exactly type to be defined as return ? Look in new:  return from line in File.ReadLines(_settings.Path)
                   select line.Split(',') into parts
                   where parts.Length == 3
                   select new InputData { X = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), Y = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) };   but InputData should be IBasic and then not possible to make ctor params correctly...

Comment: @JimmyJimm : I would encourage you to ask separate question for this in separate thread so you'll have better answer. Btw, I am not able to understand `ot possible to make ctor params correctly`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal would be to have a single repository, but multiple implementations.  Then you would like choose one of those implementations.

```
public interface IRecordRetrieverRepository<out TModel> : IDisposable
{
     IEnumerable<TModel> RetrieveAllRecords();
}
```

Our interface defines our intent, our contract.  So you would define your implementor classes, that you intend to define.

```
public class ExcelContext<TModel> : IRecordRetrieverRepository<TModel>
{
     public IEnumerable<TModel> RetrieveAllRecords()
     {
         // Actual implementation.
     }
}
```

So for brevity imagine a handful of additional context.  But your issue to your code, is the abstraction portion to return the desired implementation.

```
public interface IRecordRetrieverFactory
{
     TRecordRetrieverRepository BuildContext();
}
```

We've defined our factory interface.

```
public class RecordRetrieverFactory<TContext, TModel> : IRecordRetrieverFactory
{
     public TRecordRetrieverRepository BuildContext() => new TContext<TModel>();
}
```

Then you could simply do the following syntax.

```
using(var context = new RecordRetrieverFactory<ExcelContext, SampleModel>().BuildContext())
     return context.RetrieveAllRecords();
```

Provides a bit of flexibility, without losing your expressive code.  I didn't validate or test the code, wrote quickly but should work.  Some reflection may of been left out though.